# Integer list to ranges

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I need to convert a list of ints to a string containing all the ranges in the list.
So for example, the output should be as follows:

```
getIntRangesFromList([1,3,7,2,11,8,9,11,12,15]) -> "1-3,7-9,11-12,15"
```

So the input is not sorted and there can be duplicate values. The lists range in size from one element to 4k elements. The minimum and maximum values are 1 and 4094.

This is part of a performance critical piece of code. I have been trying to optimize this, but I can't find a way to get this faster. This is my current code:

```
def _getIntRangesFromList(list):
    if (list==[]):
        return ''
    list.sort()
    ranges = [[list[0],list[0]]] # ranges contains the start and end values of each range found
    for val in list:
        r = ranges[-1]
        if val==r[1]+1:
            r[1] = val
        elif val>r[1]+1:
            ranges.append([val,val])
    return ",".join(["-".join([str(y) for y in x]) if x[0]!=x[1] else str(x[0]) for x in ranges])
```

Any idea on how to get this faster?

Comment: belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if it works

Comment: Looks to be linear time, assuming `join()` is internally implemented to also be linear time.  You might be able to reduce the constant factor (e.g. by coding in C), but nothing can be asymptotically faster.

Comment: Takes about 0.000006 seconds for me. That's not good enough? How fast does it need to be?

Comment: @depperm Can you post a reference to that?

Comment: @ayhan http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102852/stack-overflow-vs-code-review-vs-programmers-vs-codegolf `Once you have working code, it is an important part of your professional development to have others look over your code to ... improve your overall code quality and style... if you have working code that you simply would like to review with others, your question belongs on Code Review SE.`

Comment: @StefanPochmann: It runs on an 400 mhz embedded device. It is run every second for each network rule on the device. So there are about 4k calls each second to that, and currently this is taking 300 ms. I'd like to get this down to a max of 100 ms.

Comment: @depperm: is there a way to transfer the question?

Comment: @depperm This is not a general review question where the poster wants to "improve overall code quality and style". This is a specific question and it is still on topic [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300981/performance-question-stack-overflow-or-code-review).

Comment: @ayhan I was more of pointing out if the OP has `working code that [they] ...would like to [be] [reviewed]` then post on codereview, while technically on topic here I feel like it would be more on topic at codereview

Comment: @Dakkaron Why do you sort the list? It's already sorted. If it's not always already sorted, then your example shouldn't be sorted.

Comment: This won't do much, but you could cache the value of `r` instead of retrieving it in each iteration, and since the list is sorted, the`elif` can just be an`else`. And in the final bit, `"-".join` is probably slower than just concatenating the two numbers directly, e.g. using `'{}-{}'.format(*x)`

Comment: Also, it seems like that `join` part at the end is taking up about 50% of computing time. If you don't need it, dump it and work with the lists.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: The input is not sorted. I corrected that in the example.

Comment: @tobias_k: Thanks, that should help a bit. The `elif` can't be an `else`, since if it would be it could not cope with duplicate values. I will implement the other improvements though. I need a string as output as this will be shown to the user, so I won't get away with a list, sadly.

Comment: There are many equivalent representations available: `1-3` vs `1,2,3`, for example. Does the result have to be the optimal representation? More to the point, is `','.join(map(str, list_data)))` sufficient?

Comment: @Robᵩ: in the case of `1-2` vs `1,2` I would not care, but in the case of `1-3` vs `1,2,3` I would. A lot of these ranges are quite long. So one range could go from 1-4094 (that's the longest range possible). If I had that in single non-ranged entries, it would be quite hard for the user to read.

Comment: @Dakkaron Is that just the longest range, or are your numbers actually all in that small range? That could of course be exploited to perhaps make things faster. But not if nobody knows about it! Ideally, you'd give us some actually representative data. Or at least a way to produce some ourselves. Like `[random.randint(1, 4094) for _ in range(2000)]` maybe? Not sure how we're supposed to meaningfully optimize if we have a wrong image of what you're dealing with...

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Good point, I will add that to the question. I did not thing that that would matter.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a task for the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module.

```
import itertools

list_num = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 15]
groups = (list(x) for _, x in
          itertools.groupby(list_num, lambda x, c=itertools.count(): x - next(c)))
print(', '.join('-'.join(map(str, (item[0], item[-1])[:len(item)])) for item in groups))
```

This will give you `1-3, 7-9, 11-12, 15`.

To understand what's going on you might want to check the content of `groups`.

```
import itertools
list_num = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 15]

groups = (list(x) for _, x in
          itertools.groupby(list_num, lambda x, c=itertools.count(): x - next(c)))
for element in groups:
    print('element={}'.format(element))
```

This will give you the following output.

```
element=[1, 2, 3]
element=[7, 8, 9]
element=[11, 12]
element=[15]
```

The basic idea is to have a counter running parallel to the numbers. `groupby` will create individual groups for numbers with the same numerical distance to the current value of the counter.

I don't know whether this is faster on your version of Python. You'll have to check this yourself. In my setting it's slower with this data set, but faster with a bigger number of elements.

Comment: looks scary for people who don't know Python, silly isn't it. Have an upvote.

Comment: Is this at least faster on **your** version of Python? I highly doubt it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it, on my device this solution takes about 20 times as much time as my solution.

Comment: Whoa. According to the tests on my machine (Python 3.4.1 32bit) my solution is 50% slower for those elements, but if the list gets bigger my solution is slightly faster.

Comment: If I use PyPy the original version is always faster. :-(

Comment: The device I am working on has Python 2.7.3. Cross compilation of newer Python 2.7 versions is quite hard, so I am stuck on the old version. Might be that itertools has gotten faster in Python 3. Also the list I am testing on is a lot bigger.

Comment: @Dakkaron: Use your version. In most cases I tested on different implementations of Python your version is faster. I hoped that itertools could speed things up, but there seems to be too much overhead, especially if there are a lot of groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
def _to_range(l, start, stop, idx, result):
    if idx == len(l):
        result.append((start, stop))
        return result
    if l[idx] - stop > 1:
        result.append((start, stop))
        return _to_range(l, l[idx], l[idx], idx + 1, result)
    return _to_range(l, start, l[idx], idx + 1, result)

def get_range(l):
    if not l:
        return []
    return _to_range(l, start = l[0], stop = l[0], idx = 0, result = [])

l = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 15]
result = get_range(l)
print(result) 
>>> [(1, 3), (7, 9), (11, 12), (15, 15)]
# I think it's better to fetch the data as it is and if needed, change it 
# with
print(','.join('-'.join([str(start), str(stop)]) for start, stop in result))
>>> 1-3,7-9,11-12,15-15
```

Unless you don't care at all about the data, then u can just append str(start) + '-' + str(stop) in _to_range function so later there will be no need to type extra '-'.join method.

Comment: Do you have evidence that this is faster than OP's original? If so, why?

Comment: For what data? (I hope you've did it on sorted list)

Comment: @Nf4r Who are you talking to? Me? In that case: I didn't do it at all. You yourself showed that your output ends with `,15-15`. Not with the requested `,15`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll concentrate on the performance that is your main issue. I'll give 2 solutions:

1) If the boundaries of the integers stored is between A and B, and you can create an array of booleans(even you can choose an array of bits for expanding the range you can storage) with (B - A + 2) elements, e.g. A = 0 and B = 1 000 000, we can do this (i'll write it in C#, sorry XD). This run in O(A - B) and is a good solution if A - B is less than the number of numbers:

```
public string getIntRangesFromList(int[] numbers)
    {
        //You can change this 2 constants
        const int A = 0;    
        const int B = 1000000;

        //Create an array with all its values in false by default
        //Last value always will be in false in propourse, as you can see it storage 1 value more than needed for 2nd cycle 
        bool[] apparitions = new bool[B - A + 2];
        int minNumber = B + 1;
        int maxNumber = A - 1;
        int pos;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            pos = numbers[i] - A;
            apparitions[pos] = true;

            if (minNumber > pos)
            {
                minNumber = pos;
            }
            if (maxNumber < pos)
            {
                maxNumber = pos;
            }
        }

        //I will mantain the concatenation simple, but you can make it faster to improve performance
        string result = "";
        bool isInRange = false;
        bool isFirstRange = true;
        int firstPosOfRange = 0; //Irrelevant what is its initial value
        for (int i = minNumber; i <= maxNumber + 1; i++)
        {
            if (!isInRange)
            {
                if (apparitions[i])
                {
                    if (!isFirstRange)
                    {
                        result += ",";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isFirstRange = false;
                    }

                    result += (i + A);
                    isInRange = true;
                    firstPosOfRange = i;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!apparitions[i])
                {
                    if (i > firstPosOfRange + 1)
                    {
                        result += "-" + (i + A - 1);
                    }
                    isInRange = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

2) O(N * log N)

```
    public string getIntRangesFromList2(int[] numbers)
    {
        string result = "";

        if (numbers.Length > 0)
        {
            numbers.OrderBy(x => x); //sorting and making the algorithm complexity O(N * log N)
            result += numbers[0];
            int countNumbersInRange = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                if (numbers[i] != numbers[i - 1] + 1)
                {
                    if (countNumbersInRange > 1)
                    {
                        result += "-" + numbers[i - 1];
                    }

                    result += "," + numbers[i];
                    countNumbersInRange = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    countNumbersInRange++;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Your second solution does not seem to be significantly different from OP's solution, modulo the choice of a different programming language.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest one I could come up, which tests about 10% faster than your solution on my machine (according to timeit):

```
def _ranges(l):
  if l:
    l.sort()
    return ''.join([(str(l[i]) + ('-' if l[i] + 1 == l[i + 1] else ',')) 
                    for i in range(0, len(l) - 1) if l[i - 1] + 2 != l[i + 1]] +
                   [str(l[-1])])
  else: return ''
```

The above code assumes that the values in the list are unique. If they aren't, it's easy to fix but there's a subtle hack which will no longer work and the end result will be slightly slower.

I actually timed `_ranges(u[:])` because of the sort; u is 600 randomly selected integers from range(1000) comprising 235 subsequences; 83 are singletons and 152 contain at least two numbers. If the list is sorted, quite a lot of time is saved.